# Getting scene not defined error, can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: python

Im getting scene is not defined error on all my classes. am I missing something?

```
class Survived(scene):
    quips1 = [
        'Your good at this game',
        'Way to go!',
        'I didnt think you would make it'
        'Thank for playing this game!'
    ]

    def enter(self):
        print Survived.quips [randint(0, len(self.quips1) -1)]
        exit(1)

class Scene(object):
    def enter(self):
        print "This scene is not yet configured. Subclass it and implement enter()."
```

Answer (score 2):

Python is case sensitive, you should spell `Survived(Scene)`. Also, `Scene` class should be declared *before* `Survived`, otherwise you'll get a *not defined* exception.

Something like this:

```
class Scene(object):
    def enter(self):
        print "This scene is not yet configured. Subclass it and implement enter()."

class Survived(Scene):
    quips1 = [
        'Your good at this game',
        'Way to go!',
        'I didnt think you would make it'
        'Thank for playing this game!'
    ]

    def enter(self):
        print Survived.quips [randint(0, len(self.quips1) -1)]
        exit(1)
```

Comment: Paulo Bu, Thank you so so much! I cant believe I didnt catch that, I spent hours trying to debug it. I changed my code so many times! lol

Comment: @user3479050 No worries, it happens. _The closer you look, the less you see_ hehe. Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to point out that this also happens if you forgot to add
`from manim import *` before your code...